# Why does this drawing code work on some iPads running iOS 8.1, but not others?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

i've run into a bizarre problem where my code works on some iPad models, but not others, even when they are running the same version of iOS. this simple code to draw a white circle works on my iPad 4 running iOS 8.1.1, but not on my iPad Mini Retina running 8.1.1. this is even reproducible in the simulators. it works when running on an "iPad Retina 8.1" or "iPad 2 8.1" simulator, but not an "iPad Air 8.1". when it doesn't work, it doesn't draw a small white circle. the view is blank. why is this happening?

```
@implementation MyUIViewSubclass
{
    CAShapeLayer* animationLayer;
    CGMutablePathRef smallCircle;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        smallCircle = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(smallCircle, NULL, self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2, 32, (CGFloat)M_PI, -(CGFloat)M_PI, NO);

        animationLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        animationLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
        animationLayer.lineWidth = 1;
        animationLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        animationLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        animationLayer.path = smallCircle;

        [self.layer addSublayer:animationLayer];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yeah, CGFloat (and some other Apple wrapper primitives) can end up as different types than you'd expect. For example, CGFloat might be  the float you'd expect or maybe a double, depending on the architecture.

Additionally, it's considered poor practice to put UI code in init methods. You typically want them in viewDidLoad or maybe viewWillAppear, depending on your set up.

Answer (score 1):

figured this out while i was writing the question. it didn't work on 64bit devices. when i changed the CGFloat to float, it worked. CGFloat is defined differently on 32 vs 64 bit platforms.